# React Native error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigator.push')

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

So Basically I am getting error in the title which is related to the navigator.
The error pops up when I press on the Icon.

What I basically want to do is make a Tab bar at the top that switches between three different views: feed, wiki, and message board

Here is my index.android.js: (imports Nav)

```
_renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var globalNavigatorProps = {navigator};

    switch(route.ident) {
        case "FeedView":
            return(
                <Feed
                 {...globalNavigatorProps}
                />
            );

        case "WikiView":
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text>
                        {'Hello'};
                    </Text>
                </View>
            );

        case "BoardView":
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text>
                        {'Hello'};
                    </Text>
                </View>
            );

        default:
            console.log(`Something went wrong ${route}`);
    }
}

render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <Nav />
            <Navigator
                initialRoute={{ident:"Feed"}}
                ref="appNavigator"
                renderScene={ this._renderScene }
            />

        </View>
    );
}
```

Here is my Nav.js:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

render(){

    console.log(this.props.navigator);
    return(
        <View style={{flexDirection: "column"}}>
            <View style={styles.nav}>
                <Icon onPress={(event) => this.props.navigator.push({ident: "Feed"})} name="newspaper-o" size={22}/>
                <Icon name="wikipedia-w" size={22}/>
                <Icon name="comments" size={22}/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.divider}/>
        </View>
    );
}

_changeView(type){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to implement a tabbed view there are better ways of doing it you can always use an open source module such as this one https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view 
the developer has made it in such a way that it is easy to use and the example is good enough to get through most of the part.

So instead of creating such components yourself what I would suggest is to use the modules made by the community.

Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: I actually tried using that module, but I didn't want the scroll to switch tabs and I didn't really knonw how I could change that.

Comment: hmmm you could always do it in native android and then write a bridge to it, it is simple enough let me see if I can find something else

Answer (score 2):

I dont think this is the issue, but the renderScene function won't be bound to the react component.

Try turning `renderScene={ this._renderScene }` into `renderScene={ this._renderScene.bind(this) }`

Comment: The issue is that <Nav /> does not have a reference to the navigator. You will need to place <Nav /> inside your renderScene function and pass navigator as an attribute for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

this error always occurs when you didnt bind(this),check you Icon module onPress method